# Python Convert zone id values to offset

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I need to convert offset zone id (Etc/UTC,Atlantic/Canary) values to offset values like (UTC +0,UTC +1). I have one code is working with all the scenarios except only one timezone which is **Antarctica/Casey**. I am converting this timezone to offset its giving UTC +11 but in the real the timezone is UTC +8. UTC +11 will be applicable after October.
Attaching link for reference https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/antarctica/casey

My reference code is given below:

```
splitted_timezone = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Antarctica/Casey')).strftime('%z')
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"in the real the timezone is UTC +8"*? an offset in the past?

Comment: @MrFuppes When we go to provided link the real timezone is UTC+8 but our python code is giving UTC +11

Comment: according to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Antarctica) for Antarctica's time, UTC+11 is correct for Antarctica/Casey. Paul Eggert's [tz database](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/5c79ca1f7b574798dc5f05ab0eeaae30ceb948e4/antarctica#L41) mentions that this zone changed from UTC+8 to UTC+11 in 2009, so timeanddate.com seems to be outdated...